# Remove the left spacing of an ordered list (OL)

Tags: html

By default, the ordered list looks like this:

[image]

There are some spacing on the left hand side of the list. Is there any way to remove those spacing?

Here is what I want:

[image]

On my website, the font-family and font-size will be changed by users dynamically. Therefore I am not able to preset padding-left.

Comment: Reset the padding using CSS. :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You should be able to use em for a scalable size (rather than fixed px sizing). This would allow scaling of the font size but match the scaled size when applying padding.

```
ol { padding-left: 1.8em; }
```

Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3qTv7/) to illustrate. Change the `body` font-size to different scaled sizes (try 1em, 2em, etc.) and you'll see the paragraph matches the `ol` on the left.

You may find that browsers render at different sizes. 1.8em, works with Chrome, but it may require 1.6em or 1.9em for Firefox or IE. The thing with the web is it is fluid and scalable, so shooting for pixel precision, especially when working with user-scalable fonts is almost always a no-win situation.

Answer (score 15):

> On my website, the `font-family` and `font-size` will be changed by users dynamically. Therefore I am not able to preset `padding-left`.

Why would that stop you from using `padding-left`? It's absolutely the right tool to use when you want to override the browser's default stylesheet.

```
ul {
   padding-left: 0;
   /* If you want you can change the list type from inside or outside */
   list-style: inside decimal;
}
```

Comment: In your case, the numbers won't be displayed buddy!

Comment: @PraveenKumar So long as the container doesn't have `overflow: hidden` they will be.

Comment: @PraveenKumar Depends on what design the OP is going for.

Comment: Thanks very much for alex answer! But is there any way to left align the list with the paragraph above?

Comment: @Alan Yes, adjusting the `padding` and/or `margin` will let you achieve that

Comment: when font-size is 11px and the list contains less than 10 items, the padding-left needs to be 18px. when font-size is 11px and the list contains more than 10 items, the padding-left needs to be 24px. when font-size is 14px and the list contains more than 10 items, the padding-left nees to be 28px.

Is there a general css which can be applied to all font-size and any number of list items?

Comment: But this solution ruins the alignment of list items on the left, that is when text of a list item wraps, it is no longer left-aligned with text above it, but with number of ordered list. We need a solution that removes left space without messing around with individual item's alignment.

Answer (score 7):

```
ol, ol li { margin-left: 0; padding-left: 0; }
ol { margin-left: 1.3em; }
```

The default spacing on the left may be caused by left padding or left margin of `ol` or `li`, or a combination thereof (depending on browser). So to get some specific spacing, set all those properties to zero except one of them, which you set to the value you prefer. Note that this spacing needs to be large enough for the list markers (numbers), otherwise they won’t appear or will be truncated. The value of `1.3em` (i.e., 1.3 times the font size) should be suitably large for them and leave little or no extra space on the left of them.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, by default it would be 40px. Use CSS:

```
ul {padding-left: 1.5em; list-style: decimal;}
```

Comment: Thanks for Praveen answer! 10px is good if the font-size is small. However, if the font-size is large, it will going out of the straight line. Is there any method to solve this problem? Thanks!

Comment: Simple! Give the `padding-left` in `em` and not in `px`. It is the percentage of the font size. For now, if you give `1.5em`, it stays good for **all the font sizes**, even if they **increase of decrease dynamically**. Check out. :) I have updated my answer. :D

Comment: How much ever the decimal size goes, your content remains good. The numbers will be **right aligned** and the content will be **left aligned**. It works! Trust me! :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to ensure your list is flush with the left boundary of its parent container, use your own list bullet image.

You can use the following CSS to customize your ULs:

```
UL {
  margin-left: 0;
  list-style: none outside url("myImage.png");
}
```

Hope this helps!  :)